# Switching Disqus comment disappear in admin panel

Tags: comments, disqus

I installed Disqus on my site and it works fine until last week. All of sudden, the previous comments were disappeared from admin panel. only a few recent comments are left.

**The thing I changed**:

**add '?https'** to the code as I changed my site url to https

**Change email address** as can't login with the signup email.

Disqus help is useless as I posted on there for days and no one asked.

Comment: You need to use the migration tool, forum post about it [here](https://disqus.com/home/channel/discussdisqus/discussion/channel-discussdisqus/moving_from_http_https_migration_tool_issue/) and you can find the migration tool [here](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/286778-migration-tools).